# How to add a new type of virtio back-end driver in libvirt(or Virt-Manager)?

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I've made a new back-end driver for QEMU-KVM and I'd like it to be loaded for the guest OS. I'm using Virt-Manager to launch QEMU-KVM but I can't make my back-end driver loaded and ready to be used by guest OS.

I've tried to add the following item in DOMXML for the guest OS.

```
<controller type='virtio-mydevice' index='0'>
</controller>
```

But the virsh doesn't accept the item by telling the following error.

> error: internal error Unknown controller type 'virtio-mydevice'

Is there any guide-line to meet this purpose?

Comment: I am trying to do something similar myself. I am glad you found a solution and thankful that you posted it here. I don't yet have a back-end driver myself though. What did you use as a reference, guide or example to write your own back-end driver?

Comment: Now I also want to add a new driver in qemu. Could you tell me how to do based on qemu's source code?

Answer (score 2):

I've just got the answer myself. Once you've added a new virtio back-end driver, the next thing you have to do is to add an item in QEMU option by editing qemu-option.hx. You can add your own QEMU option to load the virtio back-end driver, and virsh recognize the option once you add an option in qemu-option.hx, make and install the QEMU again.

Comment: I have some simple driver now for a new virtio back-end driver and am attempting to add an option for it to the qemu-option.hx file. I don't understand the format of the file and how it affects the XML file for the guest OS though. Could you provide some more specific details on what you had to add to it?