# Creating a new VirtIO device type in QEMU

Tags: qemu

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158244/how-to-add-a-new-type-of-virtio-back-end-driver-in-libvirtor-virt-manager/), with no avail. Since the answer is not satisfactory, I decided to ask a new one. I have created a new device type by looking at the code for other virtio devices, primarily balloon, rng and crypto.
But I'm facing a problem that I'm not sure how to resolve. I get an error saying 'virtio-bus' bus not found for device 'my-virtio-device'. And I do not know what to do about it since I have not explicitly defined a bus for my device. Virtio does it for me.

Once I'm through with this, I intend to write about it in stackoverflow documentation. I seem to find nothing on creating new virtio devices in qemu anywhere!

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem seems to be that virtio-bus is an abstract bus. So we cannot use the device directly. I had to extend VirtIOPCIDevice and define my device. VirtIOPCIDevice is attached to virtio-pci-bus. This works and my device now shows up in the guest with the `lspci` command.

I hope the short version helps. Of course, as promised in the question, I intend to write all about how I created a new virtio device in QEMU once I've finished my project.